# Excel VBA Inserting a new row under the page break

Tags: vba, excel

Currently on some huge paper work right now. so I need help.

I am looking for a way to add **3 new rows** under every page break of a specific sheet.

```
Sub WhereIsPageBreak()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
Set ws = Sheets("2ND SEM 2013")

With ws.HPageBreaks
    If .Count > 0 Then
        For Each x In .Item
            .Item(x).Location.Insert
            .Item(x).Location.Insert
            .Item(x).Location.Insert
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No Page Breaks on this Sheet"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

this is what I had made but sadly its not working.

I only have a little bit of knowledge in VBA, so sorry about such a dumb logic

Comment: if `Dim x As Integer` then you don't need to set it with `Set x = 1` , but rather `x = 1`. Aren't you getting a Runtime Error ?

Comment: already edited that, thanks for teaching. and also changed the ".count to .Item" but it gives runtime error "Argument not optional"

Comment: try the code in my answer below, let me know if it works for you

Comment: have you tried any of the solutions below ? any feedback to the people that spent their time helping you would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the loop condition because `x` already points to the page break index so you don't have to use `For..Each`.

Check the code below.

```
Sub WhereIsPageBreak()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer

Set ws = Sheets("2ND SEM 2013")

With ws.HPageBreaks
    If .Count > 0 Then
        For x = 1 To .Count
            .Item(x).Location.Insert
            .Item(x).Location.Insert
            .Item(x).Location.Insert
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No Page Breaks on this Sheet"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand how my answer isn't useful when it solves the issue posted. I hope StackOverflow would require some reasoning behind down votes. Quite unfair that after some people find the solution, they don't even "thank" the one who helped them by selecting which answer they used. Then some people have the balls of down-voting you even if your answer works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will loop through all `HPageBreaks` in `ws` sheet, and will insert 3 rows below the last row of the current `HPageBreak`.

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub WhereIsPageBreak()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PgBreak     As HPageBreak

Set ws = Sheets("2ND SEM 2013")      
With ws
    If .HPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then
        For Each PgBreak In .HPageBreaks
            PgBreak.Location.Insert
            PgBreak.Location.Insert
            PgBreak.Location.Insert
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No Page Breaks on this Sheet"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**: If you want to add 3 lines with 1 code line (instead of 3), use the code line below:

```
.Range(PgBreak.Location.Offset(1, 0), PgBreak.Location.Offset(3, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
```